# iOS App distribution for enterprise( Distributing app to a client organisation)

Tags: ionic-framework, ios-enterprise, apple-developer-enterprise

I’m part of an enterprise and we have enrolled apple enterprise license .
I’m looking for iOS enterprise distribution.  I wanted to distribute my app to my client organisation. How can I do it ?
What developer program my client organisation has to enrol .

If the client organisation is having a Apple enterprise account , can I map the app into their bundle ID and sharing the ipa files with a download link .

Will it allow the client employees can download and use the app!

Help me out

Comment: You'll probably want to checkout something like appBlade....

https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/aad.appblade?tab=overview

Comment: Thank you for your input. Apart from using a third party app, what is the best distribution method we can opt. Considering both companies having their own Apple Enterprise Account , Can we map the App to client company using their org Id or updating bundle id? In our case only client employees will be using the app .

Answer (score 0):

Applivery allows to distribute apps creating an enterprise app store, and you can use the MDM solution to distribute apps from apple app store or directly from Applivery without upload an `.ipa` to `Apple`. it is a quite good feature. They have a free trial and you can test the app distribution and app management (feature of MDM solution): https://www.applivery.com/enterprise-app-store/